# How do you identify a user in Spring using more than just the username?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring application that allows administrators to manage several sub-sections of the application, with each sub-section having its own users. The sub-sections are loaded depending on the URL that's being used to access the app. I've had some pretty simple experience using Spring security and setting up a pretty simple custom UserDetailsService, adding roles and granting authority to users, etc.

What I'd like to be able to do is have users be allowed to register under different sub-sections with the same username, and then ideally instead of loadUserByUsername in UserDetailsService for example, use something more like "loadUserByUsernameAndSubSection".  So for example user 'scott75' could be registered on subsection1.myApp.com and also on subsection2.myApp.com.

I'm not looking for anyone to write a solution for me, but hopefully point me in the right direction in terms of classes in Spring Security that could do something like this. Or, alternatively, tell me I'm crazy and to go about it another way, like building an interface around adding/removing sub-section access to/from users, or adding/removing users from sub-sections.